# How to bypass integrity checks through proxy

Tags: go, proxy, hugo

I have a Go proxy server which will proxy the incoming requests to a different nginx service, where a bunch of static files generated from hugo are deployed. The Go proxy server code is:

```
func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)
    proxy.Transport = debug.Transport{} // Set some Debug TCP options here
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

The `debug.Transport` is created like below:

```
type Transport struct {
    Transport http.RoundTripper
}

func (d Transport) RoundTrip(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    fmt.Println(r.Header)
    d.Transport = &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    return d.Transport.RoundTrip(r)
}
```

In the debug Transport, I am already ignoring the certificate checks for TLS configuration.

If I directly access the nginx url where hugo static files are served, then the static files are perfectly loaded. The static files are served fine even if I access from an nginx-ingress in addition to the nginx. However, when the requests are served via the Go proxy, then I get an error:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://<blah>/js/main.min.29b0315468c00226fa6f4556a9cebc0ac4fe1ce1457a01b22c0a06b329877383.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'Nk/s9htIgKJ5jeLFxUMWgIQGhxGZBKoEWtWEy2qYtJk='. The resource has been blocked.
```

Any idea how I can skip these `integerity` check in the Go http proxy ?

Comment: Where are you seeing that error? In your browser?

Comment: Assuming this error is in your browser, which seems most likely, no, there's no way to disable it. But you shouldn't need or want to anyway. The proper solution is to make sure you aren't modifying the data in transit. The fact that the integrity check fails means that something isn't being transferred properly.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing done to the response from the nginx where the data is being served. The entire code is what I have made above. If I visit the nginx url directly in my browser, there is no response but when it comes via the golang proxy, this happens.

Comment: `If I visit the nginx url directly in my browser, there is no "error" response` I meant above

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. But it sounds like my assumptions are correct: Your Go proxy is modifying the payload in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. The golang proxy was working fine. There was no issue in it. The hugo static pages had some references to the minified js and css, with absolute paths and that was causing the issue. When the request was coming from the golang proxy it was coming from a different url prefix and so the css and js were found to be corrupt, as the absolute path led to a different file than the one hugo static files expected (and hence the integrity failure error).

The solution was to simply add the prefix as the `baseURL` in the hugo config. More information can be found at: https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/